# But I don't want that .lib or .exp file for my COM library!

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When generating a COM dll with VisualStudio, all I *really* need is the `DllCanUnloadNow` symbol (and three related ones) to be exported from the dll itself.  *Nobody* is going to link against my library, so I'm not (at all) interested in a .lib file, nor in an .exp file.

However, I don't manage to inhibit creation of these files.    (note: I do know how it's possible to remove them in a post-build step)

These are my linker arguments:

```
/OUT:"u:/cada-nt/bin/PData.dll" 
/INCREMENTAL:NO 
/NOLOGO 
/DLL 
/MANIFEST:NO 
/DEF:"PData.def" 
/DEBUG 
/PDB:"u:/cada-nt/pdb/PData.pdb" 
/ERRORREPORT:PROMPT kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib 
                    advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib 
                    odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib
```

The question:

- Has anyone succeeded in *not* generating the .lib and .exp files?
- Does anyone know *why* these files are generated?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486020/why-com-dlls-exports-should-be-marked-private

Answer (score 18):

Visual Studio's linker has an [`/IMPLIB`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67wc07b9) option that allows you to specify the output location for your `.lib` and `.exp` files.

You can modify this option in a project's properties:

```
Configuration Properties > Linker > Advanced > Import Library
```

You might set it to the following, for example:

```
$(Configuration)\$(TargetName).lib
```

The linker will create the `.exp` file using the same name as the `.lib`.

Comment: Thats not what the OP asked for. He does not want those files created by the linker at all, not in a different folder

Answer (score 5):

There some functions inside COM library declared with as __declspec(dllexport). It means that they are exported (may be used by GetProcAdress function) and linker thinks that there is a need to link with this dynamic library (no matter it is exe or dll - in general the structure is the same) and creates *.lib and *.exp file.

to avoid creation of these files you need to remove all __declspec(dllexport) from functions declarations

Comment: This was verified for Visual Studio 2013 default compiler & linker. Target platform is either x64 or x86 or Windows.

Answer (score 3):

`/NOIMPLIB` will prevent generation of the `.lib` file.
I don't know how to avoid the `.exp` file.

Comment: `/NOEXP` according to [this bug ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/when-using-def-and-noimplib-with-linkexe-it-create/1495047). Works for me with VS 2019.

Comment: It does not work on MSVC6:
```
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option "NOIMPLIB"; ignored
```

Comment: @excitoon MSVC6? The 25-years-old compiler? It did not have this option.

Comment: @0xF works fine with wine

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how to turn them off, but you can make a post-build step to remove them, like this:

```
del $(OutDir)\$(ProjectName).lib
del $(OutDir)\$(ProjectName).exp
```

(on VS2008 it's [Project]->[Properties], then Configuration Properties->Build Events->Post-Build Events)

(note I realise you know how to do this, but this answer may help the next googler...)

Comment: A side effect of this workaround is that compilation will happen every time, because the compiler wants to recreate the files.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can hook on `kernel32.dll` `CreateFile`/`WriteFile`/`CloseHandle` and just redirect that directly into `nul`.

Answer (score -6):

why is it a problem to generate these files?  Surely if people aren't going to link directly to them all you need to do is not distribute those files and simply distribute the DLL only.

Comment: There is no urgent problem.  I even have a workaround.  It's just useless that the linker generate them.  

The files are automatically on the output folder, next to the dll that I need to distribute.  It clutters.  It annoys.

Comment: TBH I'd reckon its so low down on the list of things to do, for obvious reasons, that noone has ever bothered doing it.

Comment: -1: this is a perfectly reasonable request. I request it too, for the same reasons, those files are annoying.

Comment: @demoncodemonkey: Get used to it. I suspect you also want to get rid of those annoying obj files too ...It shocks me that some people worry about something so inconsequential and, in the end, utterly useful.

Comment: No the obj files are not so annoying because they go in the intermediate directory. The exp and lib are in my nice clean output directory... and that's the difference.

Comment: My use-case is 100% identical. I would like to not generate these files.

Comment: @Goz for me it is a problem since while the linker support generation R10000, it doesn’t support it for static libraries.