# Why COM DLLs exports should be marked "PRIVATE"?

Tags: c++, c, dll, com

When building COM DLLs, why should exports like `DllGetClassObject`, `DllCanUnloadNow`, `DllRegisterServer`, `DllUnregisterServer`, etc. be marked **`PRIVATE`** in the `EXPORTS` section of the associated `.DEF` file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you build a DLL, the linker automatically creates an *import library* for the DLL.  It contains a list of all the exported functions.  You use that import library in another project that uses the DLL.

Specific to COM servers is that those 4 exported functions are always found with GetProcAddress() and you never have an implicit dependency on a COM dll.  You always create COM objects with CoCreateInstance(), the COM plumbing takes care of locating the DLL and using GetProcAddress() to find the DllGetClassObject() function.  Same story for DllUn/RegisterServer, found by Regsvr32.exe.  And DllCanUnloadNow, found by the COM plumbing.  You therefore have no need for an import library.

Using PRIVATE ensures that the function doesn't get exported to an import library.  With all of them private, you get no import library at all.  Nothing goes wrong if you omit it, you just get an extra file from the linker that you'll never use.